# Docker + puppeteer in production

Tags: docker, puppeteer

I'm using a lib called '**node-html-to-image**' locally it works normal, when I go up with the docker I always have a problem with the docker:

> Error: Unable to launch browser, error message: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-901912/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT

I'm having this error already tried to follow several tips that the lib of 'puppeteer' in this link:

TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

the arguments to puppeteer I'm passing is:

```
puppeteerArgs: {
          headless: true,
          args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
          ]
       }
```

my DockerFile:

```
FROM node:14.15.1-alpine3.12 as build

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache alpine-sdk

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=local

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install --silent -g typescript

RUN npm install

COPY src src
COPY tsconfig.json tsconfig.json
COPY tsconfig.prod.json tsconfig.prod.json
COPY build.ts build.ts
COPY .env .env

RUN npm run build


FROM node:14.15.1-alpine3.12 as app

WORKDIR /app

RUN chown nobody:nobody /app

USER nobody:nobody

RUN ls -la

COPY --from=build --chown=nobody:nobody /app/dist ./

COPY --from=build --chown=nobody:nobody /app/node_modules ./node_modules

RUN ls -la

COPY package.json ./

ENV HOME=/app
ENV NODE_ENV=production


CMD node src/server.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it only this way, I always have to run `npm install` then remove the `node_modules` folder, run `npm install` again and then install the chromium dependency libraries

below my Dockerfile as it was at the end:

```
FROM node:14.18 as build

WORKDIR /app

ENV PORT=4000

COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm install
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get --yes install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget

RUN npm run build

COPY . .

CMD node ./dist/src/server.js
```

Comment: adding chromium dependencies helped or reinstalling node modules?

Comment: i had to install the dependencies, remove node modules then reinstall the dependencies and then install these chromium dependencies and then worked just like that

Answer (score 0):

Your docker container does not have the browser and it will not launch the one installed at the docker's host. You might like the next explanation to run chrome from a docker container:

https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8

Comment: I read the link, do you think I need to create a separate container?

Comment: I believe you need to install the browser in the same container where your app resides. If this gets too complicated it might be better for you to use a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use puppeteer docker image directly, base your work on it,
or at least learn from it

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/tree/main/docker

[image]

Comment: Im trying that docker file but its giving me errors :/